# manjaro: ZFS pool does not load during boot (using zfs-import-cache/zfs-mount) but no problem when manually running zfs-import-cache

Tags: zfs

**TLDR:**

- ZFS pool is not mounted/imported during boot even though zfs-import-cache/zfs-mount have been enabled
- looking at lsmod/journalctl, the ZFS module has been loaded
- no problem manually importing/mounting the ZFS pool by running systemctl restart zfs-import-cache and systemctl restart zfs-mount

**Here's some console commands that I ran to try and investigate the issue (the journalctl command only includes the zfs entry after I restarted the server)**

```
➜  ssh myuser@192.168.1.42
myuser@192.168.1.42's password:

Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish

myuser@myserver ~> zpool list
no pools available

myuser@myserver ~> zpool status
no pools available

myuser@myserver ~> zdb
storage-myserver:
    version: 5000
    name: 'storage-myserver'
    state: 0
    txg: 1375447
    pool_guid: 617472370471881449724
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'myserver'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 6172370456471881449724
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'raidz'
            id: 0
            guid: 1748034220473493990457
            nparity: 2
            metaslab_array: 138
            metaslab_shift: 34
            ashift: 13
            asize: 48009362538496
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 129
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 1391340476743518267315
                path: '/dev/sdb'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5027
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 130
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 1784473315434353960342
                path: '/dev/sdd'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5026
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 131
            children[2]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 2
                guid: 1148923454936736091715
                path: '/dev/sdf'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5025
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 132
            children[3]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 3
                guid: 1382088269334592035142
                path: '/dev/sdh'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5024
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 133
            children[4]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 4
                guid: 18112733835124758481
                path: '/dev/sdc'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5023
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 134
            children[5]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 5
                guid: 9964993604748294083
                path: '/dev/sde'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5022
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 135
            children[6]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 6
                guid: 463127445797571349817
                path: '/dev/sdg'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5021
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 136
            children[7]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 7
                guid: 754974834897868814160
                path: '/dev/sdi'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 5020
                create_txg: 4
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 137
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data
        
myuser@myserver ~> systemctl status zfs-import-cache
○ zfs-import-cache.service - Import ZFS pools by cache file
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-import-cache.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:zpool(8)
       
myuser@myserver ~ [3]> systemctl status zfs-mount
○ zfs-mount.service - Mount ZFS filesystems
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/zfs-mount.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:zfs(8)
       
myuser@myserver ~ [3]> journalctl | grep -i zfs
Jan 28 13:25:43 my-nas kernel: ZFS: Loaded module v2.1.2-1, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5
Jan 28 13:25:43 my-nas systemd-modules-load[323]: Inserted module 'zfs'

myuser@myserver ~> lsmod | grep -i zfs
zfs                  3899392  0
zunicode              335872  1 zfs
zzstd                 577536  1 zfs
zlua                  184320  1 zfs
zavl                   16384  1 zfs
icp                   323584  1 zfs
zcommon               102400  2 zfs,icp
znvpair               106496  2 zfs,zcommon
spl                   118784  6 zfs,icp,zzstd,znvpair,zcommon,zavl

myuser@myserver ~ [4]> sudo -i
[sudo] password for myuser:

[root@myserver ~]# systemctl restart zfs-import-cache
[root@myserver ~]# systemctl restart zfs-mount

[root@myserver ~]# zpool list
NAME             SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
storage-myserver  43.7T  18.1T  25.6T        -         -     0%    41%  1.00x    ONLINE  -

[root@myserver ~]# reboot now
Connection to 192.168.1.42 closed by remote host.
Connection to 192.168.1.42 closed.

mydesktop in ~ took 9m35s

➜  ssh myuser@192.168.1.42
myuser@192.168.1.42's password:

Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish

myuser@myserver ~> sudo -i
[sudo] password for myuser:

[root@myserver ~]# systemctl restart zfs-import-cache

[root@myserver ~]# systemctl restart zfs-mount

[root@myserver ~]# zpool list
NAME             SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
storage-myserver  43.7T  18.1T  25.6T        -         -     0%    41%  1.00x    ONLINE  -
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I need to

1. manually import the pool first (this creates zpool.cache)
2. enable (via systemctl) zfs.target, zfs-import.target, zpool-import-cache, zfs-mount

Comment: It's not `zpool-import-service`, it's `zfs-import-service`, as 2023-JUN-04 and zfs on Linux v2.1.x at least. Also your recommendation doesn't work. The last comment in the following GitHub issue solved the problem for me... but only temporarily, sadly. Still looking for a way to persist the fix. https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/8831